# Querying data through importHTML function in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importhtml

I am trying to import table data into a Google spreadsheet using the below function:

```
=ImportHTML( "http://eciresults.nic.in/StatewiseU05.htm" , "table" , 9 )
```

Following is the result I get out of it.

[image: Screenshot of table result]

But I didn’t want the content in row 1,2,3 & 4 to be displayed so I tried the query as following and got the below result:

```
=QUERY(ImportHTML( "http://eciresults.nic.in/StatewiseU05.htm" , "table" , 9 ), "SELECT * OFFSET 0")
```

[image: Screenshot 2]

But I’m still getting the NCT of Delhi content in row 1. How can I get rid of that and show only row 2 and onwards that contains the area name and subsequent data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work with this:

```
=QUERY(ImportHTML( "http://eciresults.nic.in/StatewiseU05.htm" , "table" , 9 ), "SELECT * where Col2>0",0)
```